# Overriding default express route URL handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The default express router uses `:` (colon) to mark a parameter e.g.

```
users/:id
```

But when I was using other (non node.js) framework, I have noticed that they use curly brackets, e.g.

```
users/{id}
```

And I prefer the second style because browser escapes curly brackets unlike colon (Which I want to use in my URL), and, I just like it.

So, the question is, can I override default express route URL handler?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant. The Express.js framework relies on [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) library for extracting params from urls. And its usage is hardcoded inside the [codebase](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L45), so you don't have any extension points to override that behavior.